# Asp.net POST parameter always null

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

For passing an email address I'm using ajax with POST as type.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "api/Search/UserByEmail",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({ emailAddress: userEmail }),
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) { ... }
});
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IEnumerable<Object> UserByEmail([FromBody] string emailAddress) { ... }
```

That's what Fiddler says:

```
POST http://localhost:52498/api/Search/UserByEmail HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://localhost:52498/#
Accept-Language: de-DE
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)
Host: localhost:52498
Content-Length: 35
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

{"emailAddress":"mail@example.com"}
```

Why is the emailAddress parameter always null?

Comment: This looks fine to me, have you tested constructing a request with Fiddler and posting manually? Most likely problem is with the JSON data but I can't see anything wrong with it from here. You could also try removing the `[FromBody]` attribute.

Comment: When I take out `[FromBody]`, my method is not even invoked. Here's the Routing: `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "UserByEmailRoute",
                routeTemplate: "api/Search/UserByEmail",
                defaults: new { controller = "Search", action = "UserByEmail" }
            );`

Comment: that probably makes sense, it would be expecting you to post to `api/Search/UserByEmail/emailAddress` without that - just trying to rule out things that *may* be causing the problem :) In Fiddler, if you post `=mail@example.com` as the body does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 // JS - jQuery 
 $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/UserByEmail",
        type: "POST",
        data: { emailAddress: "joe@gmail.com" },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) { if(data != null) { alert(data.toString()); } }
    });



  [Serializable]
  public class EmailFormModel {
     public string emailAddress { get; set; }
  }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult UserByEmail(EmailFormModel emailFormModel)
    {
        bool ok = emailFormModel.emailAddress != null;
        return Json(new { ok }); 
    }
```

Use a formModel and put a serializable attribute on the class and it will serialize
your javascript automatically to a C# equivalent. And you don't need to use Json-stringify.

Note a removed the          //   contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
declaration from the ajax-method. I've actually never used it.

Comment: "*You don't need to use JSON.stringify*" - you do if you want to pass data as JSON...

Comment: No if you have a serializable class as a parameter into your method it will automatically convert the javascript object to C#. And I have used this a lot myself, and it's nice!!

Comment: Yes, the point I am making though you are no longer working with JSON - the data is converted to a query string and appended to the URL.

Comment: Yeah but it's still a HTTP POST!

Comment: yep it is, but like I said you are no longer posting JSON from the client so `application/json` would have to also change to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: no I'm not sure about it, I've always used JSON as datatype in jQuery and it have been working fine.

Comment: Well I am surprised that works because you aren't posting JSON at all - you can confirm this by inspecting the packet.

Comment: Thanks, with the form model it's doing fine. If I want add another attribute to the form model, say `public string name { get; set; }`, then I need to pass a JSON object like `{ name: "", emailAddress:"mail@example.org"}`, don't I?

Comment: Yes, like that. You can add as many properties as you like. And please upvote? :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the `JSON.stringify` could be your problem. MVC will handle the serialization/deserialization of parameters for you, change it to:

```
data: { emailAddress: userEmail }
```

Comment: @user2558051 Also, take out that `FromBody` attribute, I'm pretty sure you don't need that (I've never ever heard of it!)

Comment: @mattytommo you generally do need the `[FromBody]` attribute with the WebAPI...however, I get the feeling that might be the problem here as well (see my comment).

Answer (score 0):

Modify the data property in the original ajax call to

```
data: '"' + userEmail + '"',
```

Getting some of these Web API calls to work can sometimes be a little tricky